# Sensitivity of a non-linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that we have a system of non-linear equations:
$$
f_{1}\left(x_{1},...x_{n};\theta\right)=0
$$
$$
f_{2}\left(x_{1},...,x_{n};\theta\right)=0
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
f_{n}\left(x_{1},...,x_{n};\theta\right)=0
$$
where $\theta$ denote the vector of parameters that enters possibly
non-linearly in the equations. Suppose the solution is $$ x_{1}^{*},x_{2}^{*},...x_{n}^{*}\left(\theta\right)$$

What I wish to evaluate is essential $\nabla(x_{1},...x_{n})$ with
respect to the parameter vector $\theta.$ In other words, I want
to examine how the solution values change as the parameter values
change. Please note it is generally not possible in my setting to
have a closed form solution for the $x$ variables, and the solution
is done algorithmically. What are the appropriate concepts that I
would use here?

Comment: Check the implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is differentiable with respect to $x_1,\ldots,x_n,\theta$. Then, the implicit function theorem states that

$$
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}=-\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}
$$
provided that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is invertible. If you can compute a solution $x(\theta_0)$, for some $\theta_0$, then you have a differential equation that describes the solutions to the system.

Otherwise, you just need to solve numerically for $x$ at $\theta_0$ and substitute those values to get your sensitivities.

Answer (score 1):

For a parameter set $x_1,x_2,..,x_n$, each equation specifies a property for the parameter set whether it fulfills the equation or not. So there will be property $P_k : (x_1,x_2,..,x_n)\rightarrow 2$ for each equation $k \in [1..n]$. Note that usually the area where $P_k=true$ is infinitely thin/small area of the parameter set, so it's often more useful to examine the $f_i(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)<0$ instead of $=0$ and then analyze the border between negative and positive areas.